# How can I get word between spaces in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I need get all the words of a UITextView of individual form. 
In an array for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.. Just use this if you have one space between two words:

```
NSArray *words = [textview.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

**OR** if there is the possibility of multiple spaces between words:

```
NSArray *words = [textview.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
```

Comment: if it has two or multiple spaces what you can do

Comment: Well, there can be unlimited cases just like double spaces.. It all depends on data entry. format of data. :)

Comment: see the edited post. 
@iDev now it will take care of multiple spaces

Comment: This is a naive solution. Not all languages separate words with a space, for example. If you're tokenizing natural languages, look at the `NSString` method `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` or use a `CFStringTokenizer`